# non-character input-event when using rectangular commands since version 24.4

Tags: rectangle

Since version 24.4 and till 25.1 when I want to make a rectangular copy `C-x r r RET` I got the following message: `non-character-input-event`

It appears that this problem happens only for rectangular copying but not for all other options (killing, yanking, deleting).

This happens on the following OS: Windows 7,8 and 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to type a *character* (which names the register) at the prompt **`Copy rectangle to register:`**. When you just hit `RET` that provides the event `return` for the register name, and that is rejected.

*Type, for example, `a`, and your problem should be solved.* IOW, this is pilot error combined with a UI that is not sufficiently clear.

The relevant code, which reads an input event and tries to interpret it as a character, is `register-read-with-preview`, in `register.el`.  This is the test that leads to the error message:

```
(if (characterp last-input-event)
    last-input-event
  (error "Non-character input-event"))
```

Predicate `characterp` returns `nil` for event `return`.

```
(setq foo (read-event))
```

Hit the "Enter" key.  That binds `foo` to `return`.

```
(characterp foo) ;; Returns nil.
```

Comment: Thank's. Your answer solved my problem. I interpreted the last r in `C-x r r r`  (see [rectancles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Rectangle-Registers.html#Rectangle-Registers) ) as <RET>.